# IF statement with 2 conditions (Excel)

Tags: excel

Basically I am just looking to do an IF statement with 2 conditions.

For example

```
=IF(A2>5,TRUE,FALSE)
```

The above would return 1 condition. But I would need 2 conditions like:

```
=IF(A2>5 or NULL*, TRUE,FALSE)
```

> I know the above is not a formula, I'm just trying to illustrate what
>   I'm looking for.

*NULL = Empty Cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `OR` function:

```
=IF(OR(A2>5, ISBLANK(A2)), TRUE, FALSE)
```

We could also check for an empty cell using `A2=""`, but I would prefer to use `ISBLANK()` because it is exposed agnostic to the type of data in the cell.  Coming from a more strongly typed programming language, it may feel strange to be comparing a cell to both a number and a string in the same equation.

Comment: Was just going to ask how ISBLANK is different then " ". Thanks. Didn't realize could use OR, as I just googled "2 conditions". I guess illustrating it got me closer to the solution then I thought :p

Comment: What is I want to do IF < 5 but not if it's blank?

Comment: @kazzi Try this: `=IF(AND(A2 < 5, NOT(ISBLANK(A2))), TRUE, FALSE)`

Answer (score 1):

you can do

```
=IF(OR(A2>5,A2=""), TRUE,FALSE)
```

Comment: I was right there the whole time. Didn't realize could use OR as a function.